# Android ImageProxy equivalent in c++ dlib img

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, dlib

I have android cameraX streaming frame for doing analysis, for analysis I'm using dlib face detector. So I'm passing frame to JNI that calling dlib face detector. But I'm having trouble knowing the data type ImageProxy at java to c++ img.

Answer (score 0):

The `ImageProxy` type has a `getPlanes` method that returns an array of [planes](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageProxy.PlaneProxy) (either RGB or YUV) , each of which provides access to a `ByteBuffer` and some metadata like pixel and row stride.

You can pull the pixel data from these ByteBuffers in JNI. I don't know dlib enough to tell you if it accepts the planes separately or if you need to merge the planes beforehand.

Comment: based on dlib example http://dlib.net/face_detection_ex.cpp.html, dlib is accepting parameter "array2d<unsigned char>"

Comment: Sounds like it *might* be happy with a matrix of grayscale pixel values then. Either you take the Y plane from the camera, or reconstruct it by averaging the R, G and B planes.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider a more off-the-shelf approach like MediaPipe or MLKit until you gain a deeper understanding of AI and Android.